# ASP.net on ISS web page design

Tags: asp.net, html

I want to create a web page displaying the status of several systems. Each one will be represented by a square box.

The boxes will fill up in either red or green (<50% will be red and >50% will be green).

Can this be constructed in HTML? Can anyone guide me to the best language to use for this if not. Also I have to use ASP.net to do this.

Comment: Sure this can be constructed. Whats the main problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: mainly using ASP.net to construct the web pages and display information on them. My idea for the box, was to have 10 smaller boxes put together to represent 1 and so when the % to fill up the box is given, it can be rounded to the nearest 10 and that many boxes filled up in the corresponding colour. Like a progress bar, but vertical. I'm just not sure how to go about doing this in ASP.net

Comment: So whats the event when you want to change the color of your boxes?

Comment: a scripts going to run comparing two outputs. Based on the results of this comparison the box will fill up showing how well the outputs match. I'll make the script output a value and if the value is >50 then the box will fill up that amount in green. If the value is <50 then the box will fill up that amount in red.

Comment: Can't you do that in JS by adding appropriate CSS styles to your boxes depending on the result of your script?
Sorry I still don't understand whats the main problem here.